# Kendo angular form validation in TabStrips

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Im using angular 4 and kendo for angular.
I have form that contains tabs.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #f="ngForm" (submit)="update(f.valid)" novalidate>
    <kendo-tabstrip>
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Main settings'" [selected]="true">
         .
         .
         .
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
        <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Working time'">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <span> mail to</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="k-textbox" name="mailTo" [(ngModel)]="mailTo" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12" [hidden]="!f.submitted">
                    <small [hidden]="mailTo" class="text-danger">Please enter mail to</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
    </kendo-tabstrip>
    <button kendoButton type="submit" [primary]="true">Save</button>
</form>
```

On submit, first tab is active and second is not, input with `name="mailTo"` in second tab is not validate and validation passes. Probably because second tab is hidden. Is there a way to validate inputs in inactive tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include [keepTabContent]="true" this will persist all tab content in the DOM even when the tab is not selected.
That way all your input validators are run on inactive tabs when you press Save

```
<kendo-tabstrip [keepTabContent]="true">
    <kendo-tabstrip-tab [title]="'Main settings'" [selected]="true">
...
```